# Тип поля SET

Tags: sql, mysql

Создана таблица с полем

```
 named SET('1','0') DEFAULT '0';
```

Никак не пойму поведение поля.
Идет вставка значений и получаю след.значения:

```
INSERT('67')  //1,0   почему 2 значения?
INSERT('0')   // 0
INSERT(0)   // '' -пустая строка почему DEFAULT не страбатывает?
INSERT(1)  //1
INSERT('1') //1
```

Comment: у меня не получается повторить ваш опыт: Schema Creation Failed: Data truncated for column 'named' at row 1: 


http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. если вставляете строку, то это должны быть значения из множества через запятую. левые значения указывать нельзя. Будет либо warning с отсечением невалидного значения, либо error как в комментарии [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto).
2. если вставляете число, то значение будет интерпретировано как битовая маска. 0 - пустое множество, 1 - первый элемент множества, 7 - первый, второй, третий элементы.
3. default у вас так не сработает. default будет если в списке вставляемых полей у вас не будет указано это поле вовсе. Так работают все default'ы, не только для set'а.

ЗЫ Читайте [доки](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html), они - рулез!

Comment: Спасибо за коментарий.Еще раз убедился в том,что нужно учить битовые операции.